# How to set the ReadTimeout for JPA connections

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

How can i set the read timeout (socket#sotimeout) on a jpa connection.
Do i have to set javax.persistence.query.timeout or is it spring.datasource.socketTimeout?
Any hint how i could test that the value is really set?

I'm using jdbc-postgresql with spring-jpa and hikaricp.

Comment: What i've figured out is that the timeout of hikari.validationTimeout is set as "socket#sotimeout"  before PoolBase#isConnectionAlive is called. But the value on the socket is always reseted after the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket#sotimeout can be set by yaml properties.
It has to be look like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        socketTimeout: 20 #default 0s
```

Comment: Note that the time unit here is _seconds_. That is internally translated to the actual milliseconds value that the Socket API uses. So a value of 5000 might not be what people should use, if they intend to express "5 seconds".

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle DB, use the following preference:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=6000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).